# How to extract chraracters from column with very differently data in R

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

I'm trying to extract some specific characters from a column that are formatted very differently and i have some problems with the code. I'm using the next DF:

```
details<-data.frame(details=c("MG/0,9 ML SOL. INY. JRP",
                        "MG CM REC",
                        "MG LIOFIL P/INF. IV FAM",
                        "MG/ 5ML SOL. INY",
                        "MG/ML SOL.ORAL FC 100-200ML"))
```

I'm trying using `extract()` function but i don't know how to code de regex part:

```
extract(details,"details",c("detail_1","detail_2"),regex = ??)
```

I'm want to finally get the next two columns:

```
      detail_1              detail_2
1    MG/0,9 ML         SOL. INY. JRP
2           MG                CM REC
3           MG  LIOFIL P/INF. IV FAM
4      MG/ 5ML              SOL. INY
5        MG/ML SOL.ORAL FC 100-200ML
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `extract` we can do :

```
tidyr::extract(details, details, c("detail_1","detail_2"), 
               regex = '(.*(?:MG|ML)[^.$])(.*)')

#   detail_1              detail_2
#1 MG/0,9 ML          SOL. INY. JRP
#2        MG                 CM REC
#3        MG   LIOFIL P/INF. IV FAM
#4   MG/ 5ML               SOL. INY
#5     MG/ML  SOL.ORAL FC 100-200ML
```

For `detail_1` we extract everything until we encounter either `"MG"` or `"ML"` and which is not end of the sentence. For `detail_2` we extract everything after that.

---

Another option using `dplyr` and `stringr` would be :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

details %>%
  mutate(detail_1 = str_extract(details, ".*(MG|ML)[^.$]"), 
         detail_2 = str_remove(details, detail_1))
```